# Rotate sphere based on lat/lng

Tags: 3d, geometry

Ok so i have an api to a globe that I can only move by setting the x y z axis tilt. (the camera cannot move.) I need to be able to map lat/lng to it. So basically take lat/lng and rotate in x y z and show the point in the center of the screen.

The setup can basically be visualized with this picture...
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ECEF.png

One other thing, the globe is offset in Z such that the prime meridian is at 0 0 135 tilt.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So, This might be a bit late for your use but if you have your latitude and longitude angles as Theta (lat) and Phi (long) then the following rotation will move your point to the center of the screen

Here I assume that the north pole is at (0,0,1) i.e z=1

First set X axis tilt as -Theta
Then set Z axis tilt as -Phi

This should center your point

You might need to add offsets depending on how the sphere is built